# Can i do this Report withe BIRT

Tags: birt, crosstab

I am new in BIRT and i try to do a report from a DB ,  [This is a overview of my DB](http://hpics.li/5bce46f), in the end I want to have something Like  [this](http://hpics.li/1dd862f) for one person it's possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to display data in a crosstab in BIRT - see [here](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/202-birt-cross-tab-example--basic-/) or [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_birt_report_guide/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/eclipse_birt_report_crosstab.17.1.html) for explanations and examples.

Comment: thank you , for the time I could do that [ http://hpics.li/3ae1b9c ] and that give my [ http://hpics.li/85ec7f1 ] but I want  in the line a week and every week the same treatment :)